# Parse Migration (PHP SDK)

Tags: parse-platform, migration

I have a PHP Website which is using Parse -PHP SDK.
May I have steps/understanding, what changes i need to do in the project itself?
I have migrated my db already to mongolab.What I need to do next? Where can I found proper guide .

Answer (score 0):

You would need to setup your instance of parse-server. There is a number of options and providers you can use that make this process easy or you can setup your own server.

Some providers ( there are many more ):

- Heroku and mLab
- AWS and Elastic Beanstalk
- Google App Engine
- Microsoft Azure
- SashiDo
- Digital Ocean
- Back4app

The git docs for parse-server will explain more in detail on the setup.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

You can also make use of the migration document that gives step to step details on how to setup form start to finish.

http://parse.com/migration